# Acumatica - PXRedirectToFileException not redirecting in 2019R2

Tags: acumatica

We're currently going through upgrading and ran into an issue where we can no longer redirect a user to one of our files. We've tried all of the different redirect methods, but for example purposes this is the easiest to show. If you use the below action and feed it a file it does nothing. However, if you change the "false" to "true" (for forcedownload) it will indeed download the file. This reinforces what we have seen with the other redirect methods. The system will not let you redirect to a URL that has .ashx in the url.

Is this an intentional change or is this a bug? We tried both 19.205.0023 and 19.207.0026

Thanks for your help =)

```
public PXAction<UsrDesign> viewFile;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "View File")]
[PXButton()]
protected virtual void ViewFile ()
{
   string fileName = Design.Current.ProofFile; // whatever file you want, in our case it comes from custom screen
   UploadFile uploadFile = PXSelect<UploadFile, Where<UploadFile.name, Equal<Required<UploadFile.name>>>>.Select(this, fileName);
   UploadFileMaintenance fileGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();
   var file = fileGraph.GetFile((Guid)uploadFile.FileID);

   throw new PXRedirectToFileException(file, false);
}
```

Comment: Well force download would be the way to go isn't it? A web page can only suggest to the browser what to do. There's no guarantee a page will be able to push a download to the browser, it does depend on external factors. If you can't download files at all from browser I would think something else is going on, try from a different machine.

Comment: When forceDownload is equal to true - the file will be downloaded in the same tab, otherwise, a new tab will be opened. I suppose your browser may block this new tab in case of false forceDownload flag.

Comment: I was using the PXRedirectToFileException as an example. In 2019R2 it will not let you redirect to ~/Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID=  -- Prior to 2019R2 this worked fine and we could redirect users to PDF files in new tabs.